# Error when renaming .plist resource

Tags: xcode, resources, plist

I'm having an issue when attempting to rename a .plist file.
I've added to my project using : `New File... -> Resource -> Property List`

When I'm changing its name from x-code  (by clicking twice on the file and then tipping the new name) I get an error popup from x-code :

`error : bad index file sha1 signature fatal : index file corrupt`

How could I rename my file?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the error message comes from GIT (and not from Xcode itself), take a look at this article: https://makandracards.com/makandra/5899-how-to-fix-a-corrupt-git-index

> How to fix a corrupt git index
>
> If your git index for some reason becomes invalid, no need to worry.
>
> Your index is corrupt when you see this error running usual git
>   commands like git pull, git status, etc.:
>
> **error: bad index file sha1 signature fatal: index file corrupt**
>
> Though it sounds bad, your changes are still there. Fix it by first removing
>   the index file, then resetting the branch:
>
> rm .git/index git reset You should be all good now.

Comment: My project is on a local host (for security reason). Could it be the reason of my problem? If not, could you please give more details for your answer? I'm not used with mac environment (just developing app with x-code)

Comment: I have no more details, if you are using git you can fix your problem as written ...

Comment: Ok, I'm not using git. I'm going to create a new .plist with a new name.

Comment: Are you sure? Take a look at Xcode->File->Source Control->Repositories

Comment: You are right, Organizer informs a Git type for my project's Repository. However, for the Location, it's exactly where my project is.

Comment: I managed to do the first command, but the second one gives "git: command not found"

Comment: Problem solved : Command Line Tools was not installed. Btw, thanks for your help.